# How to enable the eclipse internal browser (Ubuntu 12.10)?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, browser, gtk

I have installed Eclipse 4.2 x64 on Ubuntu 12.10 x64. I need to use the internal web browser but it is disabled by default.

The "Use internal web browser" radio button in preferences -> General -> web browser  is disabled.
How can I enable it?

I have installed Eclipse 4.2 x64 in another PC that uses Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and the internal browser works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe to be posted in [http://askubuntu.com/](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that there a problem with the Mozilla GTK in 12.10. So try to install the Webkit engine.

```
apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have a [supported browser](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux) installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Mozilla GTK